# Django: tinymce HTML format

Tags: django

I just installed django-tinymce however when I display the content I'm getting HTML format. How can I fix this?

```
Something <p>Some <strong>random </strong>text 123 123 123 <strong><br /></strong></p> admin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use safe filter.
For example:

```
{{ your_html|safe }}
```

By default Django template engine escapes HTML to prevent XSS attacks. By using this filter you say the HTML is safe and can be rendered normally.

Comment: You'rev welcome. I suggest to study about XSS attack. It's good to know about it.